# Call to a member function get() on null, how to resolve?

Tags: php, laravel

How do I write a function which will check to see if a column is set to 50?

If it is 50, it is NOT updateable...

```
foreach ($orders as $order) 
{

 // Gets updatable status
 $updatable = $this->updateable($order->id);

 // Saves new externals (create), if updateable
 if ($updatable != false) 
 {
      $this->create();

  }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\External;

trait Updateable
{
    // If external status is not 50, it is updateable
    public function updateable($id) {
        // If External status is 50, it is not updateable
        $externalStatus = External::find($id)->get('status');

        if($externalStatus == 50) {
            return $updateable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I could change it to findOrFail but then how do I catch the error?

Comment: do you want it to just return false if it doesn't find a model by id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Check this & try

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\External;

trait Updateable
{
    // If external status is not 50, it is updateable
    public function updateable($id) {
        // If External status is 50, it is not updateable
        $externalStatus = External::find($id);

        if($externalStatus->status == 50) {
            return $updateable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works... 

I also do...        

$externalStatus = External::find($id);
        if (isset($externalStatus) && $externalStatus->status == 50) {
            return $updateable = false;
        }

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (to reduce code).

```
public function updateable($id) {
    // If External status is 50, it is not updateable
    return External::where('id',$id)->where('status', 50)->first(); //or you could return ! Extenal... and omit ! in if.
}
```

`first()` will return data if its not empty, sort of equivalent to `true`. If it is empty, it will return `null`, equivalent to `false`. So inside `foreach` you could do:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) 
{
    // Saves new externals (create), if updateable
    if ( ! $this->updateable($order->id) ) {
     $this->create();
  }
}
```

Regarding your question about catching error using `findOrFail`, you could use `try..catch()` to catch `ModelNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you want to have `true` returned from this method under the right conditions, not just `false` or `void`/`null`, though I am not sure how you want to handle non existing models:

```
namespace App\Traits;

use App\External;

trait Updateable
{
    public function updateable($id)
    {
        if (! ($external = External::find($id)) {
            return false; // model not found
        }

        return $external->status != 50;
    }
}
```

Then your loop:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if ($this->updateable($order->id)) {
        $this->create();
    }
}
```